# Query Parse Users based on username

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm trying to search for a `PFUser` based on the `username` property in cloud code using JavaScript.

Here is my JavaScript code that I took from their documentation:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendAccountAdditionRequest", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("username", request.params.adminUsername);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success("A request has been sent");
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("An account with that number does not exist. Please tell your administrator to sign up before you are added.");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is how i'm calling it from my app:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendAccountAdditionRequest", withParameters: ["adminUsername": phoneNumber.stringValue]) {
    (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        self.showBasicAlertWithMessage("Error", title: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to run this I get the following error output in xCode:

```
[Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0)
```

I have another function in my cloud code that I can successfully call so I know that I'm able to reach it. I don't understand what is making my function invalid :(

Comment: your functions look normal, are you sure you "reloaded" the parse-server and that you are using the cloudCode that contains this function? try to put there some console.log(); and let us know if the function gets trigger at all, this seems like environment problem to me...

Comment: you were right. it was an environmental thing :)